# How to simulate artificial data for logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, simulation

I know I'm missing something in my understanding of logistic regression, and would really appreciate any help.

As far as I understand it, the logistic regression assumes that the probability of a '1' outcome given the inputs, is a linear combination of the inputs, passed through an inverse-logistic function. This is exemplified in the following R code:

```
#create data:
x1 = rnorm(1000)           # some continuous variables 
x2 = rnorm(1000)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2        # linear combination with a bias
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         # pass through an inv-logit function
y = pr > 0.5               # take as '1' if probability > 0.5

#now feed it to glm:
df = data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2)
glm =glm( y~x1+x2,data=df,family="binomial")
```

and I get the following error message:

> Warning messages:
>   1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
>   2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

I've worked with R for some time now; enough to know that probably I'm the one to blame..
what is happening here?

Comment: The way you simulate your data looks weird to me. If you want, for an alternative more standard way, you can have a look here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12857/generate-random-correlated-data-between-a-binary-and-a-continuous-variable/12858#12858

Comment: @ocram: you are right; this is a duplicate question!

Comment: I did run an erroneous simulation, as @Stéphane Laurent explained. However, the problem was [perfect separation in logistic regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45803/logistic-regression-in-r-resulted-in-hauck-donner-phenomenon-now-what), a problem I was not familiar with, and that I was rather surprised to learn about.

Comment: @zorbar: it was in my response to your question (now deleted).

Comment: @user603: I probably missed your response; Thanks anyway

Answer (score 81, accepted):

No. The response variable $y_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable taking value $1$ with probability $pr(i)$.

```
> set.seed(666)
> x1 = rnorm(1000)           # some continuous variables 
> x2 = rnorm(1000)
> z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2        # linear combination with a bias
> pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         # pass through an inv-logit function
> y = rbinom(1000,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable
> 
> #now feed it to glm:
> df = data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2)
> glm( y~x1+x2,data=df,family="binomial")

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, family = "binomial", data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
     0.9915       2.2731       3.1853  

Degrees of Freedom: 999 Total (i.e. Null);  997 Residual
Null Deviance:      1355 
Residual Deviance: 582.9        AIC: 588.9
```

Comment: You're right - I've missed this step. thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I had a question regarding the way you simulate data. When we simulate data for linear regression, we also simulate a noise (\epsilon). I understand that logistic function is a function of the expectation which by itself cancels the noise out. Is that the reason that you don't have any noise in your z ?

Comment: @Sepehr Linear regression assumes a Gaussian distribution. The "noise" is just an interpretation of the variability around the mean, but this is not a noise added to the response : the response is written as $\text{mean response} + \text{noise}$, this is just an interpretation. The logistic regression assumes the response has a binomial distribution, and similarly there's no noise added to the response.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, exactly. I completely get. Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent How should I generate the data in the case where the coefficients have l2 regularization on them?

Comment: @DushyantSahoo L2 regularization is a method if estimating coefficients from sample data. It has nothing to do with how to generate data in a simulation. You can generate your data however you like and then use L2 regularization to estimate the coefficients in the sample you drew from the data-generating process.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why there isn't  an 'error' term in `z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2` like this `z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + rnorm(1000 )`?

Comment: Oh! I see: because we are not modelling the individual `y_i` values, but we are modelling the mean with the link function.

Answer (score 5):

LogisticRegression is suitable for fitting if probabilities or proportions are provided as the targets, not only 0/1 outcomes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def logistic(x, b, noise=None):
    L = x.T.dot(b)
    if noise is not None:
        L = L+noise
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-L))

x = np.arange(-10., 10, 0.05)
bias = np.ones(len(x))
X = np.vstack([x,bias]) # Add intercept
B =  [1., 1.] # Sigmoid params for X

# True mean
p = logistic(X, B)
# Noisy mean
pnoisy = logistic(X, B, noise=np.random.normal(loc=0., scale=1., size=len(x)))
# dichotomize pnoisy -- sample 0/1 with probability pnoisy
dichot = np.random.binomial(1., pnoisy)

pd.Series(p, index=x).plot(style='-')
pd.Series(pnoisy, index=x).plot(style='.')
pd.Series(dichot, index=x).plot(style='.')
```

Here we have three potential targets for logistic regression. `p` which is the true/target proportion/probability, `pnoisy` which is p with normal noise added in the log odds scale, and `dichot`, which is pnoisy treated as a parameter to the binomial PDF, and sampled from that. You should test all 3 -- I found some open source LR implementations can't fit `p`.

Depending on your application, you may prefer pnoisy.

In practice, you should also consider how the noise is *likely* to be shaped in you target application and try to emulate that.