# Simulating data for logistic regression with a categorical variable

Tags: r, logistic, simulation

I was trying to create some test data for logistic regression and I found this post [How to simulate artificial data for logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46523/how-to-simulate-artificial-data-for-logistic-regression)

It is a nice answer but it creates only continuous variables. What about a categorical variable x3 with 5 levels (A B C D E) associated with y for the same example as in the link?

Comment: sample(x=c(1, 2, 3), size=1, prob=rep(1/3, 3)) generates one of "1", "2", or "3" with equal probability.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but how do I associate the probabilities here with the y of the post I mentioned? I copy some code from that post  'code' > set.seed(666)
> x1 = rnorm(1000)           # some continuous variables 
> x2 = rnorm(1000)
> z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2        # linear combination with a bias
> pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         # pass through an inv-logit function
> y = rbinom(1000,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable 'code'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The model**

Let $x_B = 1$ if one has category "B", and $x_B = 0$ otherwise.
Define $x_C$, $x_D$, and $x_E$ similary.
If $x_B = x_C = x_D = x_E = 0$, then we have category "A" (i.e., "A" is the reference level). Your model can then be written as

$$
\textrm{logit}(\pi) = \beta_0 + \beta_B x_B + \beta_C x_C + \beta_D x_D + \beta_E x_E
$$
with $\beta_0$ an intercept.

---

**Data generation in R**

**(a)**

```
x <- sample(x=c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"), 
              size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=rep(1/5, 5))
```

The `x` vector has `n` components (one for each individual). Each component is either "A", "B", "C", "D", or "E". Each of "A", "B", "C", "D", and "E" is equally likely.

**(b)**

```
library(dummies)
dummy(x)
```

`dummy(x)` is a matrix with `n` rows (one for each individual) and 5 columns corresponding to $x_A$, $x_B$, $x_C$, $x_D$, and $x_E$. The linear predictors (one for each individual) can then be written as

```
linpred <- cbind(1, dummy(x)[, -1]) %*% c(beta0, betaB, betaC, betaD, betaE)
```

**(c)**

The probabilities of success follows from the logistic model:

```
pi <- exp(linpred) / (1 + exp(linpred))
```

**(d)**

Now we can generate the binary response variable. The $i$th response comes from a binomial random variable $\textrm{Bin}(n, p)$ with $n = 1$ and $p =$ `pi[i]`:

```
y <- rbinom(n=n, size=1, prob=pi)
```

---

**Some quick simulations to check this is OK**

```
> #------ parameters ------
> n <- 1000 
> beta0 <- 0.07
> betaB <- 0.1
> betaC <- -0.15
> betaD <- -0.03
> betaE <- 0.9
> #------------------------
> 
> #------ initialisation ------
> beta0Hat <- rep(NA, 1000)
> betaBHat <- rep(NA, 1000)
> betaCHat <- rep(NA, 1000)
> betaDHat <- rep(NA, 1000)
> betaEHat <- rep(NA, 1000)
> #----------------------------
> 
> #------ simulations ------
> for(i in 1:1000)
+ {
+   #data generation
+   x <- sample(x=c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"), 
+               size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=rep(1/5, 5))  #(a)
+   linpred <- cbind(1, dummy(x)[, -1]) %*% c(beta0, betaB, betaC, betaD, betaE)  #(b)
+   pi <- exp(linpred) / (1 + exp(linpred))  #(c)
+   y <- rbinom(n=n, size=1, prob=pi)  #(d)
+   data <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
+   
+   #fit the logistic model
+   mod <- glm(y ~ x, family="binomial", data=data)
+   
+   #save the estimates
+   beta0Hat[i] <- mod$coef[1]
+   betaBHat[i] <- mod$coef[2]
+   betaCHat[i] <- mod$coef[3]
+   betaDHat[i] <- mod$coef[4]
+   betaEHat[i] <- mod$coef[5]
+ }
> #-------------------------
> 
> #------ results ------
> round(c(beta0=mean(beta0Hat), 
+         betaB=mean(betaBHat), 
+         betaC=mean(betaCHat), 
+         betaD=mean(betaDHat), 
+         betaE=mean(betaEHat)), 3)
 beta0  betaB  betaC  betaD  betaE 
 0.066  0.100 -0.152 -0.026  0.908 
> #---------------------
```

Comment: @ocram -- could give some intuition for good choices of parameters and choice of probabilities of components (part a)? How would changes to these affect the exercise?

Comment: @dchandler: The parameters and probabilities were chosen arbitrarily, for the sake of illustration.

Comment: @ocram -- understood. However, I'm looking for intuition on what would be good coefficients so that I could run more extensive simulations. For instance, if I wanted to simulate lasso regressions, I may be interested in adding meaningless variables (w/ zero coefficients) and seeing how the # of meaningless variables and the magnitude of the non-zero coefficients on meaningful variables affect the simulation.