How to calculate McFadden's r-squared for just one variable in R?
For my logistic regression I use  McFadden's R-squared (similar to R-squared but for logistic models). However, McFadden's R-squared calculates the effect of the overall model, and I want to know the effect of a single variable in the model. I already managed to calculate the partial r squared for a single variable for a linear regression model (using the package: sensemakr), but I do not know how to do it with McFadden's R squared for logistic regression. Does anyone have any ideas? I work in RStudio.

As far as I know, the only thing like a "partial McFadden R^2" is to run the regression with just the variable you are interested in. But I doubt this is what you want.

Thank you! That is possible but the effect of the variable I'm interested in is different if I exclude the control variables. So the partial McFadden R^2 might also be different then. But maybe it is the only option as I don't know if something like a " partial McFadden R^2" even exists :) .

(I am quoting from my answer here.)
USUAL PARTIAL $R^2$
Let's look at the equation.
$$
R^2_{partial} = \dfrac{SSE(reduced) - SSE(full)}{SSE(reduced)}
$$
In words, this compares the reduction in SSE from the reduced to the full model to the SSE of the reduced model. (We know the full model will have lower SSE.)
When the reduced model is the intercept-only model, the reduced model always predicts $\bar{y}$. This means that $SSE(reduced) = SSTotal$. Thus...
$$
R^2_{partial} = \dfrac{SSTotal - SSE(full)}{SSTotal}
$$
This is the usual $R^2!$
Therefore, much as $R^2$ describes the  variance (proportional to $SSE$) of a model, compared to the variance of the intercept-only model (naïvely guessing $\bar{y}$, no matter the predictor values), partial $R^2$ describes the variance explained by a model, compared to a more complex model than the intercept-only model.
MCFADDEN PARTIAL PSEUDO $R^2$
McFadden's pseudo $R^2$, instead of considering the sum of squared residuals for full and intercept-only models, considers the log loss.
$$
L(y, \hat y) = -\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^N\left(
y_i\log(\hat y_i) + (1 - y_i)\log(1 - \hat y_i)
\right)\\
y_i\in\left\{0, 1\right\}\\
\hat y_i\in\left(0, 1\right)
$$
For a McFadden partial pseudo $R^2$, I would calculate analogously. First, calculate the log loss for your model. Then calculate the log loss for a model that omits the variable for which you want to know the McFadden partial pseudo $R^2$.
$$
\dfrac{
\text{LogLoss}\left(
\text{Reduced}
\right) - \text{LogLoss}\left(
\text{Full}
\right)
}{
\text{LogLoss}\left(
\text{Reduced}
\right)
}
$$
Below, I give an example in R.
library(ModelMetrics)
set.seed(2024)

# Simulate a logistic regression
# https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46525/247274
#
N <- 1000
x1 <- rnorm(N)           # some continuous variables 
x2 <- rnorm(N)
z <- 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2        # linear combination with a bias
pr <- 1/(1+exp(-z))         # pass through an inv-logit function
y <- rbinom(N, 1, pr)      # bernoulli response variable

# Fit the full model with both x1 and x2
#
L_full <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial)

# Fit the reduced model with just x1
#
L_reduced <- glm(y ~ x1, family = binomial)

# Calculate log loss for both models
#
loss_full <- ModelMetrics::logLoss(
  actual = y,
  predicted = predict(L_full, type = "response")
)
loss_reduced <- ModelMetrics::logLoss(
  actual = y,
  predicted = predict(L_reduced, type = "response")
)

# Calculate McFadden partial pseudo R^2
#
(loss_reduced - loss_full)/loss_reduced # I get 0.4757003

